# itextsharp irenderlistener interface for getting image and text at the same time

Tags: c#, itext

how come when i debug, itextsharp irenderlistenter after implementing it does not go to renderImage method? even if i have image as the first object to appear in the page before text.

is there a parameter to say 'includeimages=true'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your image a bitmap image or a vector graphic image? iText(Sharp) currently only supports bitmap images here. If it is a bitmap, please supply a sample PDF illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, after putting breakpoint inside of the renderimage method and the only breakpoint it has, in just loops the text first before images.